# why does my desktop still act a lot like fedora 20 even after upgrading to fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

I upgraded to fedora 21 a few weeks ago (via fedup), but some stuff still feels like Fedora 20.

First example: `cat /etc/fedora-release`  does say `Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)`. But, nevertheless, my gcc is still 4.8, `gcc --version gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)`, and

Second example: when I try to install software, I often get fedora20 packages, even though the same package is available in fedora21 builds (example: `yum install latexmk shows Installing: latexmk noarch 4.42-1.fc20`, but fedora does have a same version latexmk for fedora21 (see http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=2276.).

How can I get started fixing this?

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying to do a `yum update`? If you used `fedup` it may have left f20 a few rpm's installed.

Comment: I do get several kinds of errors and strange things. Here is a notable set of errors: <code>"Found 278 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:"</code> all 278 errors seem to be duplicates, example: <code>glibc-2.20-7.fc21.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.18-16.fc20.x86_64</code>.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something went a little wrong in Fedup. Since every system which has been running for a while and has had some packages added and removed is effectively unique, this, unfortunately, happens sometimes.

From your comments, you have some duplicate packages and other issues; to fix this, make sure you have the `yum-utils` package installed, and run

```
sudo package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

and then

```
sudo package-cleanup --problems
```

(If there are remaining ones, clean them up.

Then, run

```
sudo yum distro-sync
```

which will make sure that the packages you have installed match the version you're actually running.